# Masterpage widen and remove margins RSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a Masterpage which I used on my webform and webcontrol. I have a big left margin from the left of the navigation pane and another big margin on the right side. How do I reduce the margin to maximize all the realestate?

Thanks,
.

Comment: Is there anything you can show us(generated html,screenshot,css,aspx markup,code,...)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply a css on your page, to change the state of the current css class on this element. Set the css class with the `!important` to overwrite the current css class.

on your webform, try this:

```
<style>

.your_left_column_style {
    margin-left: 10px !important;
}

</style>
```